# force a cell refresh before running a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script that relie on a value in a cell to run correctly. Now the script is link to a button.
Now if the user enters a value and click on the script without moving to another cell, the update value use, the script will use the previous value.

Is there a way to make sure the cell refresh before the rest of the script run?

Comment: Put as a first line: `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

Comment: Use onEdit and (oldValue != e.value).

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.flush() doesn't work and onEdit() won't be generated until return or move to another cell.  The edit is not complete without a return or moving to another cell.

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: How about checking `getActiveCell`?